# Biot-Savart equation not behaving as expected

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am currently in the process making a large electromagnet with a permeable core that has the following specs:

- I = 250A
- N = 300
- L = 0.25m
- relative permability of core = 230000

$B=\frac{\mu_r \mu_0 NI}{L}$

When I plug these values into the above equation, I get 86350 Teslas, which I am certain cannot be correct. Am I using this equation incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

Magnetic cores experience *saturation*: the magnetization of the material (which is what reinforces the $\mathbf B$ field) increases in proportion to the applied field only *up to a limit*, at which point the proportionality ceases to hold.

Effectively, the relative permeability of your material is only 230000 for low values of $H=\frac{IN}L.$ You can see this on the *magnetization curve* for your material. Wikipedia [has one for a few common materials](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Magnetization_curves.svg). The relative permeability you quote is the slope of this curve near the origin. Far from the origin, the slope flattens out greatly and $B$ no longer grows nearly as quickly with $H.$ Unless you are given a corrected value of $\mu_r$ for the high field regime, the equation $B=\frac{\mu_r\mu_0NI}L$ is not particularly useful and you should be directly referencing a magnetization curve.

Pure iron has a similar relative permeability (around 200000) at low fields. However, looking up its magnetization curve shows that it will actually top out at around $B\approx1\,\mathrm{tesla}$ at your value of $H.$